# How do I make a Minecraft server with Legend of Notch Installed?

Tags: mods, minecraft-java-edition

I have seen this really awesome mod and thought that would be cool to have a server with it(just for my friend and I). I have tried myself to install it on a server but then it didn't want to start. Yes I know that I have to have the mod installed at my own PC as well.

How do I get Legend of Notch installed to my Minecraft Server?

Comment: Are you sure this is an SMP mod?

Comment: no im not as i said i know nothing about mods on server :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Legend of Notch](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1292954-132-rpg-forge-the-legend-of-notch-pre-release-107/) is an SSP-only mod. This means that while you're free to install it and play it by yourself, it will not work in multiplayer.

Comment: Good dammit :D `;..;´

Comment: Haha, sorry. If you're looking for a good SMP mod that adds a lot of new stuff, I'd recommend Tekkit.

Comment: yeah thats a good modpack but i want a rpg mod D:

Comment: I didn't really play hack/mine, but I think it was RPGish

Comment: it's not that fun it to easy D:

Comment: Oh, okay. Well, no idea then.

Comment: You might be able to do LAN multiplayer, but the mod being designed for only one character means it'll probably just cause bugs.